# exe runs much slower in the case of subprocesses of nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an `exe` program that runs much slower in the case of subprocesses than when it runs as a single process. Is it because of some restrictions on subprocesses imposed by nodejs? Is there any way I can evade those restrictions?

I tried to run the `exe` as a subprocess of nodejs. Every procedure in the program was as much as a 100 times slower than if I had run it by double clicking on it.

```
const path = require('path')
const {spawn} = require('child_process')
const DIR = path.join(__dirname, dir)
const init = () => {
  return spawn(
    DIR,
    [],
    {
      cwd: null,
      env: null,
      stdio:'ignore'
    }
  );
}
let ls = init()
```

I wonder if there is any way to make the program work properly.

Note: It is an electron application.

Comment: A little context on how you are running this may help. Are you running inside a VM or Docker container? When running non-standalone are you running any debugging software which may slow it down?

Comment: I dont know how to descript this, is that like " electron 5.0.0,  nodejs 10.15.0, window10 "?@AdanRehtla

Comment: Just running it on Windows 10? Not using Docker or any Virtual Machines?

Comment: This report in the electron issue tracker might be useful to you: [Overall speed of electron based products](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5672)